# Android, JFIF in json responseText - ImageView

Tags: android

I've to display an image that I get from a server as json in an ImageView. But instead of an image url, I'm getting a lot of characters like this..

```
����JFIF��C      

 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C           

2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222����"��   
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�  
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�����
```

I'm guessing this is the Image's raw data or JFIF. I searched stackoverflow, but could find only converting from base64, or showing image from a url.

How do I get the image from this and display it in the ImageView.

Regards.

Comment: Are you telling us that BitmapFactory cannot handle this if you have that in a byte array?

Comment: sorry, I only meant that I don't know how to show this in an ImageView. I new to programming and dont know much about BitmapFactory and all. Please be kind enough to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I did not had to convert the response into Base64. just converted it into bitmap and set it to the ImageView. It was a very silly question due to my lack of knowledge. Hope my code helps someone in the future

```
HttpClient httpClient = ServiceHelper.getHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(RestApiPaths.GET_PROFILE_PICTURE);
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(emergencyCardPhoto); 
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            entity.consumeContent();
        }
    }
}
catch(ClientProtocolException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Well it was not an image contained in a json response as you said. It was only the image itself. Good you found the solution though.

Comment: `I did not had to convert the response into Base64.`. No. You ment: The response was not base64 encoded so i did not have to base64 decode the response to a byte array first.

Comment: `imageView.setImageBitmap(emergencyCardPhoto); `. How is this possible in the middle of internet code? You are not using any `StrictMode` statements are you? It looks like you do. Get rid of them and place your code in an AsyncTask or thread.

Comment: Its in asynch task. I just posted the important part only. Thank you for your  replies. cheers.